# subclass of stringstream and nullptr

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

This simple code can be compiled by clang++, but not with g++.
Is there anything undefined in it?
(the template function is needed to make clang happy)
GCC 8.2.0 (used with -std=c++17) says operator<< is ambiguous, it shows a list of candidates, but my template function is not even among them.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <sstream>

template<class Out>
Out&& operator<<(Out&& out, std::nullptr_t) {
  out << "nullptr";
  return std::forward<Out>(out); }

struct A : std::stringstream { };

int main() {
  A{} << nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is caused by [Bug 51577](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51577) of GCC.

Your code results in the instantiation of `std::__is_insertable<std::basic_ostream<char>&, std::nullptr_t&, void>` in libstdc++, then let's look at [the definition of this struct](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/c0a8dacad95511feaa8bd962aafb969f99d3250b/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/ostream#L659-L666):

```
template<typename _Ostream, typename _Tp, typename = void>
  struct __is_insertable : false_type {};

template<typename _Ostream, typename _Tp>
  struct __is_insertable<_Ostream, _Tp,
                         __void_t<decltype(declval<_Ostream&>()
                                           << declval<const _Tp&>())>>
                                  : true_type {};
```

If everything goes right, your `operator<<` is invisible here<sup>1</sup>, then the partial specialization is disabled by [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), and `__is_insertable` is instantiated normally to be a derived class of `std::false_type`.

Now due to Bug 51577, your `operator<<` is visible here, causing the parital specialization to be a perfect match. However, when instantiating `__is_insertable`, your `operator<<` is invisible for some reason, so an error occurs because of ambiguous overload for `operator<<`.

---

Note GCC 9 [compiles](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Cg7Jb-) this code. This is because there is a [new overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)

```
basic_ostream& operator<<( std::nullptr_t );
```

... added in C++17, so `__is_insertable` can be successfully instantiated whether or not your `operator<<` is visible. The bug is still there.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is because [[temp.dep.candidate]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.dep.candidate#1):

> For a function call where the postfix-expression is a dependent name, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules ([basic.lookup.unqual], [basic.lookup.argdep]) except that:
>
> - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup, only function declarations from the template definition context are found.
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces ([basic.lookup.argdep]), only function declarations found in either the template definition context or the template instantiation context are found.

Your `operator<<` cannot be found from the template definition context of course. The arguments are of types `std::basic_ostream<char>` and `std::nullptr_t`, so the [associated namespaces](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lookup.argdep#2) do not contain the global namespace. As a result, your `operator<<` shouldn't be found.